# I accidentaly changed file system type and wrote a couple files. How do I get my old files back?

Tags: data-recovery, ntfs, ext4

So, I had a windows laptop that I installed Linux onto. Fedora onto the storage drive, and Kubuntu on a separate NVMe drive. A lot of my data was on the Fedora drive, then I put the old Windows drive back into the laptop, and it apparently thought the Fedora drive was supposed to be an NTFS storage drive because now the drive is called DATA, all that's on it is:

```
$RECYCLE.BIN
    S-1-5-18
        desktop.ini
    S-1-5-21-4039987853-288116331-4186372247-1001
        desktop.ini
Recovery
    Logs
System Volume Information
    AadRecoveryPasswordDelete
    ClientRecoveryPasswordRotation
    EDP
        Recovery
    IndexerVolumeGuid
    tracking.log
    WPSettings.dat
```

What's not there is my personal files or Fedora system files. If you could help me get my personal files back, that would be great.

Comment: Are you telling that the Fedora partition has been overwritten?

Comment: It sounds like you need professional data recovery assistance - the kind that costs money.

Comment: Have you tried to take "the old Windows drive" out of the pc again and reboot ? When you add a new drive to a computer, the device-names may change ( /dev/sda to /dev/sdb and so on), Also please update your question with the output of `blkid`